# What should i do to resolve the issue. If the issue is Invalid device-id, then how should i change?

Tags: appcelerator-mobile, titanium-studio

I installed the appcelerator on my windows 7 (64 bit) machine. 
Then i created a new html based project for windows app development.
The issue is that When i run the emulator in Appcelerator, i get the following error :

[ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "0"
For help, run: titanium help build
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\NSPL10_Test.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:89:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Windows_Phone_SDK you need Windows 8.1 64-bit Pro+